# Install Kalarm, drags in many Akonadi packages, but fails to start and says Akonadi is required?

Tags: kde, akonadi

Freshly installed Kubuntu 19.10

I install Kalarm, which drags in 39 other packages, most with "akonadi" or "pim" in their name.

I then try to start Kalarm, and get a panel saying that "The Akonadi personal information management service is not running. This application cannot be used without it.". Just below is a big "Start" button but clicking on it does nothing.

If I start `kalarm` in a terminal I see:

```
org.kde.pim.kidentitymanagement: IdentityManager: There was no default identity. Marking first one as default.
org.kde.pim.kalarm: Preferences::setNoAutoStart: Error writing autostart file: "/home/me/.config/autostart/kalarm.autostart.desktop"
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Unable to execute akonadi_control, falling back to D-Bus auto-launch
```

Clicking on the Start button adds another:

```
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Unable to execute akonadi_control, falling back to D-Bus auto-launch
```

Creating the `/home/me/.config/autostart/kalarm.autostart.desktop` removes the 2nd line but doesn't solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Versions:

```
plasmashell 5.16.5
Qt: 5.12.4
KDE Frameworks: 5.62.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

Edit: So installed mariadb and akonadi server (5.11.3). Rebooted. Now starting `kalarm` says:

```
 org.kde.pim.kidentitymanagement: IdentityManager: There was no default identity. Marking first one as default.
Failed to register /MainApplication on DBus
""
```

`akonadiselftest` reports two errors:

- MySQL Server default configuration not found
- No resource agents found

Current installation status:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                              Version            Architecture Description
+++-=================================-==================-============-==========================================
ii  akonadi-backend-mysql             4:19.04.3-0ubuntu3 all          MySQL storage backend for Akonadi
un  akonadi-backend-postgresql        <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  akonadi-backend-sqlite            <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  akonadi-server                    4:19.04.3-0ubuntu3 amd64        Akonadi PIM storage service
un  akonadiconsole                    <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  libakonadi-kf5                    <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libkf5akonadicontact-data         4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1 all          akonadi-contacts - data files
un  libkf5akonadicontact5             <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libkf5akonadicontact5abi1:amd64   4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1 amd64        Akonadi contacts access library
ii  libkf5akonadicore-bin             4:19.04.3-0ubuntu3 amd64        Tools for Akonadi core library
un  libkf5akonadicore5                <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libkf5akonadicore5abi1:amd64      4:19.04.3-0ubuntu3 amd64        Akonadi core library
ii  libkf5akonadimime-data            4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1 all          akonadi-mime - data files
ii  libkf5akonadimime5:amd64          4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1 amd64        Akonadi MIME handling library
ii  libkf5akonadiprivate5abi2:amd64   4:19.04.3-0ubuntu3 amd64        libraries for the Akonadi PIM storage serv
ii  libkf5akonadisearchpim5:amd64     4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1 amd64        Akonadi search library
un  libkf5akonadisocialutils5         <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libkf5akonadiwidgets5abi1:amd64   4:19.04.3-0ubuntu3 amd64        Akonadi widgets library
un  libkf5akonadixml5                 <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libkf5libkdepimakonadi5:amd64     4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1 amd64        KDE PIM Akonadi library
ii  libkf5mailtransportakonadi5:amd64 19.04.3-0ubuntu1   amd64        mail transport service library for akonadi
```

Comment: In case you don't get help here, `man kalarm` points to http://www.astrojar.org.uk/kalarm/ which suggests https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=229. At least one KDE developer (and kalarm author) is active at the second link. See [this](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=229&t=164049#p426801) for example.

Comment: If you're asking there, please provide the output of `plasmashell --version` and `kf5-config --version`. An option, if you're on Kubuntu 19.10, is to open KInfocenter, use "copy to clipboard" and paste the contents there. This would indicate whether you're using the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=eoan) which provides Plasma 5.1**8.2** as opposed to whatever 19.10 initially shipped with.

Comment: @DKBose Added versions to answer

Comment: I have no experience with kalarm but I just tried in a VM with Kubuntu 19.10 (Plasma **5.18.2** from the backports-ppa I linked to above.) I had to install `akonadi-server` as well as `kdepim-runtime`. After a reboot, I get what appears to be a function GUI. Could you please try?

Comment: Will try later today, and keep you posted.

Comment: I just checked and it seems to be working for me at least with a simple "Hello World" type of display alarm.

Comment: By the way, Kubuntu 20.04 will not have any akonadi-dependent applications included by default: https://phabricator.kde.org/T12486.

Comment: OK, that works. If you make that an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the dependencies it pulls in at the time of installation in Kubuntu 19.10 (minimal install option), `kalarm` requires the additional installation of `akonadi-server` and `kdepim-runtime`.

---

This issue will be fixed in the near future: see [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/76538-Kalarm-dependencies-in-Kubuntu-20-04?p=434802&viewfull=1#post434802) and [here](https://salsa.debian.org/qt-kde-team/kde/kalarm/-/commit/fba1a4052f809cb30652c3e8d2fbc2aa471bbd66).